How to use watchexec crate to monitor only files not found in .gitignore
The standard example for using watchexec is:
use miette::{IntoDiagnostic, Result};
use watchexec_signals::Signal;
use watchexec::Watchexec;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let wx = Watchexec::new(|mut action| {
        // print any events
        for event in action.events.iter() {
            eprintln!("EVENT: {event:?}");
        }

        // if Ctrl-C is received, quit
        if action.signals().any(|sig| sig == Signal::Interrupt) {
            action.quit();
        }

        action
    })?;

    // watch the current directory
    wx.config.pathset(["."]);

    wx.main().await.into_diagnostic()?;
    Ok(())
}

how do I modify the config to use the .gitignore file in the current directory to filter out events? Or even to filter out certain files manually? This supposedly used to be some kind of default, and could be set up by using vcs_filter=true but I do not find that anywhere in the current crates, nor have I managed to figure out how to use the watchexec_ignore_filterer to do so.

It seems the notify crate was better for this than watchexec. I would still be interested in the answer.
